# keyboard shortcut to set terminal tab title

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I like to work in linux without using mouse, because of that I would like to know is there any method to set keyboard shortcut to set terminal tab title.

thank you for attention.
Regards,
Hayk

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not a programming question.
2. Yes, it's possible in most terminals with appropriate escape sequences. It depends on which terminal emulator you use, though.

Comment: thank you for answering(I am using gnome-terminal), but where I can put my question(to place it in right place :))?.

Comment: I think unix.stackexchange.com might be a better place. But I'm no expert on the matter. ;)